# Type mismatch issue

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo

I'm working on play 2.3, I want to update a collection while insert to another collection. Below is the code which is throwing error.

```
def create(message : MessageThread) : Future[reactivemongo.core.commands.LastError] = {
    collectionThread.insert(message.copy(
                createDate = Some(new DateTime()),
                updateDate = Some(new DateTime())
    ))
}

def updateMessage(messageId : JsValue) : Future[reactivemongo.core.commands.LastError] = {
    collection.update(Json.obj("_id" -> (Json.obj("$oid" -> messageId))), 
                      Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("isRead" -> false,
                               "lastRepliedDate" -> Some(new DateTime()))))
}

def createThread = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[MessageThread].flatMap { message =>
            create(message).flatMap { created =>
                updateMessage(request.body \ "messageId").flatMap{ updated =>
                    Created
                }
        }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("invalid json")))
}
```

I'm calling update and create from createThread. I'm not able to send the result back

Error is as follows

```
type mismatch;
found   : controllers.Messages.Status
required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
```

As I'm still early with learning `scala`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot try your code so I have to *compile* it in my mind. That said, it seems to me the problem is here:

```
request.body.validate[MessageThread].flatMap { message =>
    create(message).flatMap { created => 
      updateMessage(request.body \ "messageId").flatMap { updated =>
        Created
      }
    }
}
```

Instead of the third `flatMap` try `map`, as follows:

```
request.body.validate[MessageThread].flatMap { message =>
    create(message).flatMap { created => 
      updateMessage(request.body \ "messageId").map { updated =>
        Created
      }
    }
}
```

Actually, since it does not seem you're using `created` and `updated` you could just use:

```
request.body.validate[MessageThread].flatMap { message =>
    create(message).flatMap { _ => 
      updateMessage(request.body \ "messageId").map { _ =>
        Created
      }
    }
}
```

If you prefer you could use an equivalent for comprehension:

```
for {
  message <- request.body.validate[MessageThread]
  _ <- create(message)
  _ <- updateMessage(request.body \ "messageId")
} yield Created
```

Comment: It's still not working. Now it's throwing
    type mismatch;
    found   : scala.concurrent.Future[controllers.Messages.Status]
    required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[?]

Comment: You need to respond with a JSON. I suggest you read play doc thoroughly top-down, if you haven't got time try to figure it out here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonHttp